# How to prevent emacsclient starting a new frame every time?

Tags: emacsclient, frames

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running with Emacs 24.3.
On computer startup, `emacs --daemon` is executed, and I have modified the `emacs24.desktop` to take `emacsclient -c -a ""` as exec parameter. However, whenever I try to open a file a new frame opens every time.
**Is there a way to make the file appear in a preexisting frame as a new buffer?**

By *“open a file”* I mean using either GUI file manager or using terminal by `emacsclient -nc [filename]` or `emacsclient -nc -a "" [file]`.

*EDIT*: What seems to be happening is that emacs is opening a new "OS window" (as in Emacs frame) with every file; however, I am able to access all the buffers in the same emacs frame. Still, having multiple emacs frames in irritating even though I don't have to switch through them. Closing the frame manually removes the buffer too.

Is there a way to suppress the behavior of opening the new frame every time?

Comment: What is the "-nc" option you have in your commandline. I see "-nw", "-c", "-n" but no "-nc" option when I do `emacsclient -help`.

Comment: `-n` is for `no-wait` while `-c` was to create new frame (I didn't realized it created new frame _every_ _time_). Without `-c`, `emacsclient` starts emacs in the `-nw` mode for some reason.

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure if -n and -c can be merged into -nc.

Comment: It gives the same behavior. But yes, that was careless on my part; thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your included option of `-c` is causing this. Per the man page,

> -c, --create-frame  create a new frame instead of trying to use  the  current Emacs frame.

Remove this option from your command and Emacs should refrain from creating a new frame (AKA Window).

Comment: If I don't use `-c`, `emacsclient` opens emacs in the terminal for some reason

Comment: That is only true with the '-nw, -t, --tty' option. What command are using without '-c' that is opening Emacs in the terminal?

Comment: `emacsclient path_to_file`

Comment: On my pc `emacsclient filename` only opens emacs in the terminal if there is no frame already present. If a frame is present, the buffer is opened in the frame.

Comment: @Vamsi Ah, you're right, thanks. Simple things!