# Get emacsclient to reuse exising X-window, iff any

Tags: frames, emacsclient, x11

I'm trying to set my desktop environment to use emacsclient to open text files.

I would like only one emacs x-window to be opened. Yet I don't know which command can be used to have an x-window created if and only if no emacs x-window already exists.

- The command `emacsclient %F` doesn't work when no x-window exists.
- The command `emacsclient -c %F` always creates a new x-window.
- I don't know how to check for the existence of an emacs x-window.

Which command / script should I use ?

---

By *x-window* I mean 'what a window is for the window-manager'

Answer (score 0):

```
emacsclient -a /usr/bin/emacs %F
```

If you also want to use daemon mode, see [Make emacsclient create a frame only if there isn't one already](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12894/make-emacsclient-create-a-frame-only-if-there-isnt-one-already)