# Correct commandline options (by pure elisp) for emacsclient to create a new frame only if the file is not already open otherwise switchs to it

Tags: frames, emacsclient

If I invoke emacsclient with `emacsclient -na runemacs file1` emacsclients switch to the frame containing file1.
But if later I invoke emacs with `emacsclient -na runemacs file2` emacsclient opens file2 in the existing frame of file1.

On the other hand `emacsclient -cna runemacs file1` always creates a new frame regardless of if file1 is already opened or not.

I prefer that emacsclient creates a new frame of a file if that file is not already open in the existing frames, otherwise emacsclient switchs to the frame containing it.

I guess I should send some elisp code by `-e` option to the emacsclient for checking this but I was not able to find the right code.

There is a related question [Make emacsclient create a frame only if there isn't one already](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12894/make-emacsclient-create-a-frame-only-if-there-isnt-one-already) without an accepted answer. The upvoted answer there uses a bash script hence not a pure elisp solution.

Comment: Why is it important for it to be pure elisp?

Comment: One reason can be an elisp solution also works an the platforms where bash is not available.